Calculating volume profile in columnar database
I am having price , volume received every seconds to my tick table , from there i need materialiszed view , where it automatically calculate volume profile for me .Volume profile in the sense I need for unique price it must add up all the volume.I am trying this in clickhouse.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vp_1min_view
TO vp_1min
AS
SELECT 
    symbol,
    price,
    toStartOfMinute(timestamp) AS minute,
    SUM(volume) AS total_volume,
    COUNT(DISTINCT price) AS trade_count
FROM tick
GROUP BY symbol, price, toStartOfMinute(timestamp)
ORDER BY symbol, minute, price;


Here above I need only single 148 price with columns summed up.But no matter what I try price is not getting unique for that particular minute.I tried all AI tools , and non seems to help.

Can you share some input data ?

its simple ohlc thats updated every 1 second with variable price

Testing in any other major DB gives the correct result, so you may have to think reporting a bug and replace the built-in toStartOfMinute() by your own solution.
(note that count(distinct price) will always return 1 since price is part of the group by... so you may remove it, may be it will solves the problem too...)

it could be a bug in group by or in the wrapper function toStartOfMinute() or in combination of both.
try date_trunc see if that makes a difference:
SELECT 
    symbol,
    price,
    date_trunc('minute', timestamp) AS minute,
    SUM(volume) AS total_volume,
    COUNT(DISTINCT price) AS trade_count
FROM tick
GROUP BY symbol, price, date_trunc('minute',timestamp)
ORDER BY symbol, minute, price;


it was formatting issue in grafana, once i set decimal it was fine.

Also , it takes few seconds to merge the data.

Could you share SHOW CREATE TABLE vp_1min FORMAT Vertical?
Does your table have engine=AggregatingMergeTree or engine=SummingMergeTree?
If not, then looks like your expectation from Materialized View are wrong.
Materialized View is just AFTER INSERT TRIGGER which works with every rows only inside one INSERT statement INTO tick table.
So you need to apply AggregatingMergeTree engine
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree
and use SELECT .. FINAL
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from#final-modifier
